# How draw polygons consecutively (triangles and diamonds)

Tags: java, rendering, polygon

I have a array of objects that need to rendered as polygons.

This array contains elements that are triangles and/or diamonds. This array will have its items constantly permuted, so the draw method needs to be constantly refreshed.

I tried this but I just got draw the polygons one after the other, however I need the polygons edges stay together of the edge of the next element.

```
Form[] f = new Form[]{triangle, triangle, diamond, triangle, diamond, diamond, triangle, diamond};
```

Then it will  be rendered like:

example 1

[image]

Another example:

```
Form[] f = new Form[]{triangle, triangle, triangle, diamond, diamond, diamond, diamond, triangle};
```

example 2

[image]

Whats a good practice to solve this problem?

Comment: You need the points of the edges to be the same in consecutive shapes.

Comment: I was thinking in draw a full polygon shape, and after draw the line edges by that shape. But I don't know if this could be a good strategy.